# How do you get Thunderbird's replies to show up at the top of the email?

Tags: email, thunderbird, formatting, email-client, reply

How do you get Thunderbird's replies to show up at the top of the email, rather than the bottom? I have provided an example below:

**Initial email:** On 1/11/2012 5:17 PM, m****@n******.com wrote:

> How did the day go?
>
> N***************
>   9***************
>   A*************
>   888-888-8888
>   (f)999-999-9999
>   m****@n********.com
>   CONFIDENTIALLY NOTICE
>   This email message and any attachments are only for the use of the intended recipient and may contain information that is privileged, confidential or exempt from disclosure under applicable law.  If you are not the intended recipient, any disclosure, distribution or other use of this e-mail message or attachments is prohibited.  If you have received this e-mail message in error, please delete and notify the sender immediately.  Thank you.

**My reply:** The day went great.

-- 
A*****
N*********
Phone: 666-666-6666
Fax: 777-777-7777
Email: a******@n******.com


The copy and paste is sloppy, but the point should be easy to get. I want my reply to be at the top of the email. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A reply to an email will be placed wherever it was placed when the replying party typed it in.

If you want the cursor to be placed at the top of the quoted original message rather than the bottom, then go to

> Tools / Account Settings / Composition and Addressing / Automatically quote the original message / start my reply from the top of the email